# Exclude Extra Error Information from RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR

Tags: oracle, plsql, error-handling, exception, oracle11g

I have raised an error message in a PL/SQL trigger and it works fine except that it returns more than the error I specify to the application. In addition to the custom error I get information about the line that the error happened on and the trigger.

For example it will get

```
 ORA-20111: There is a custom error here
 ORA-06512: at "{schema_name}.{trigger_name}", LINE 2
 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger {schema_name}.{trigger_name}<br>
 .Operation canceled.
```

What I actually want is:

```
ORA-20111: There is a custom error here
```

How do I remove the extra information from the error message before it is returned to my application? My testing code below...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CUSTOM_ERROR
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON {SCHEMA_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME} FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20111, 'There is a custom error here');
END;
```

Comment: And your code looks like? i don't see any code you posted. How are you handling the exceptions?

Comment: @LalitKumarB There is no handling. Adjusted the code for you. I want the user to see this error from the application. It just shows the error it receives from Oracle. I want the error to be EXACTLY what I put in the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR and nothing more

Comment: But that is not going to be helpful by not raising already-defined exception and having ONLY user-defined exception.

Comment: @LalitKumarB The important thing to address is my question and not if what I need is useful from other points of view.

Comment: @LalitKumarB The other important thing to note is that it is an 'application error' which is different from a system error. I indeed promise you it will be useful to who gets it and it will tell them EXACTLY what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: You can't remove the line info from the error message that is generated. You might be able to hide it from the caller's end, but manually - extracting the first line from the string, essentially. You can't suppress it in SQL\*Plus when you issue a plain insert/update, for example. So how are you calling statement that will generate the exception?

Comment: @AlexPoole It's an application called Map Info which is accessing the table and sending an insert/update statement to the database. Unfortunately it's a COTS product and we can't customize it with our current skills (although maybe it can be done). The client wants the error message to be user friendly. If, as you say, it can't be done from the Oracle side then we will have to explore other options.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR**.

For example,

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    custom_err EXCEPTION;
  3    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( custom_err, -20099 );
  4  BEGIN
  5    raise_application_error( -20099, 'This is a custom error' );
  6  EXCEPTION
  7  WHEN custom_err THEN
  8    dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm );
  9  END;
 10  /
ORA-20099: This is a custom error

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

`PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT` is to give a custom error number, which could vary in a range from **-20001** to **-20999**

However, you need to take care of the **already-defined exceptions** from being raised.

For example,

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    custom_err EXCEPTION;
  3    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( custom_err, -20099 );
  4    v number;
  5  BEGIN
  6    SELECT empno INTO v FROM emp WHERE empno = 1234;
  7    raise_application_error( -20099, 'This is a custom error' );
  8  EXCEPTION
  9  WHEN custom_err THEN
 10    dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm );
 11  END;
 12  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 6


SQL>
```

There is a **NO_DATA_FOUND** exception thrown. You could suppress that, however, it will leave the error stack with additional messages.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    custom_err EXCEPTION;
  3    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( custom_err, -20099 );
  4    v number;
  5  BEGIN
  6    SELECT empno INTO v FROM emp WHERE empno = 1234;
  7    raise_application_error( -20099, 'This is a custom error' );
  8  EXCEPTION
  9  WHEN no_data_found THEN
 10     raise_application_error( -20099, 'This is a custom error' );
 11  WHEN custom_err THEN
 12    dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm );
 13  END;
 14  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20099: This is a custom error
ORA-06512: at line 10


SQL>
```

I would always want to log the errors as verbose as possible. The raise_application_error is good for a custom message to be displayed on the application, however, I would log all the errors in the program.

Please have a look at:

- **dbms_utility.format_error_stack**
- **dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace**

Comment: That doesn't pass an exception to the application though. You can send a string back, sure, e.g. as an output parameter - wrapping the statement that causes the trigger to fire in a procedure - but then you're using your own error handling process, not built-in exception handling.

Comment: @AlexPoole It would be a nightmare to see dbms_output in production code. Yes, you are right, what I mean is pass it as an OUT parameter fro a PL/SQL unit  to the application.

Comment: As I understand this answer, I would have to get the application (MapInfo) to change the insert/update SQL it sends to the database to be a procedure call which gets a return value? Unfortunately I cannot change how the client application functions so it's not possible :(